# Google cloud Pubsub not working without external IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, publish-subscribe

I have one Compute engine without external IP.

The instance send message in a topic with python script.

However, isn't work. I have timeout.

But if a add an Static or Ephemaral IP is work fine.

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the External IP, you can't even access to the instance via SSH through the GCP Console as it has no internet connection. Therefore, as the PubSub client libraries need to use the `pubsub.googleapis.com` endpoint, that's the reason why isn't working. You'll need to use the [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#top_of_page) which allows to use some of the Google APIs including Pub/Sub

Comment: Thanks. I use a "bastion" to accès of others instances in my private network.

Comment: You'll need to use the [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#top_of_page) which allows to use some of the Google APIs including Pub/Sub

Comment: No problem, good to know it helped you. I've edited my answer